# ng-options and binding to complex data model

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

http://plnkr.co/edit/eayVNWWEXE6rUfddTdgg?p=info

I have this customer object

```
   $scope.customerFound = {
    "id":"1",
    "customerId":2,
    "customerLabel":"light", 
    "valueId":55,
    "valueLabel":"TOP"
  }
```

and this list that I loop through ng-options:

```
  $scope.customerList = [
      {
            "valueId":55,
            "valueLabel":"LUOL"
      },
      {
            "valueId":65,
            "valueLabel":"TOP"
      },
      {
            "valueId":75,
            "valueLabel":"BOT"
      },
    ]
};
```

html

```
  <select ng-model="customerFound" ng-options="customer.valueLabel for customer in customerList track by customer.valueLabel | orderBy:'valueLabel'">
        <option selected value="" disabled id="text-disabled">  Select </option>
  </select>

{{customerFound}}
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eayVNWWEXE6rUfddTdgg?p=info

If you notice the plnkr when I select from the drop down, my whole customerFound object gets changed to just the two properties from custermorList.

Is there parsimonious way to just update the valueId and valueLabel in my customerFound object without having to do a bunch of data transformation?

Thanks

Comment: Just bind `customerList` to array of objects with all the properties you need. Or you need to use ng-change to set the actual object based on the selected id.

Comment: I'm not understanding your suggestion, mind elaborating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just restructure your data a little bit - if you make the two properties you want to change their own object, then it becomes very simple:

http://plnkr.co/edit/betys07Cq9I1QRmP7HIs?p=preview

```
$scope.customerFound = {
  "id":"1",
  "customerId":2,
  "customerLabel":"light", 
  "value": { 
    "id":55,
    "label":"TOP"
  }
}

$scope.customerList = [
  {
    "id":55,
    "label":"LUOL"
  },
  {
    "id":65,
    "label":"TOP"
  },
  {
    "id":75,
    "label":"BOT"
  },
]

<select ng-model="customerFound.value" ng-options="value as value.label for value in customerList track by value.label | orderBy:'valueLabel'">
    <option selected value="" disabled id="text-disabled">  Select </option>
</select>
```

If you can't restructure your data, then you could do something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/had9Q9qkmpfDYydUzBNE?p=preview

Essentially, use a tmp ng-model, and use ng-change to set the properties:

```
 $scope.setSelected = function(o) {
  for (var k in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      $scope.customerFound[k] = o[k];
    }
  }
}

<select ng-change="setSelected(tmp)" ng-model="tmp" ng-options="customer.valueLabel for customer in customerList track by customer.valueLabel | orderBy:'valueLabel'">
    <option selected value="" disabled id="text-disabled">  Select </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I agree, but what if I can't restructure my data? :\

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I had in mind to do but I was looking for some magical ng-options magic to get around this. After searching and not understanding the docs, i'm going to go ahead with this solutions. Tanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can't rearrange your data as suggested in some of the other comments/answers, here's a version using `ng-change` that I think answers your question:

```
$scope.updateCustomerFound = function() {
  $scope.customerFound.valueId = $scope.customerFoundSelect.valueId;
  $scope.customerFound.valueLabel = $scope.customerFoundSelect.valueLabel;
};
```

and updating your `select`:

```
<select ng-model="customerFoundSelect" ng-change="updateCustomerFound()" ...>
```

My forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBwKVSEfSKN6aC72JFpw?p=preview).